# Register-WMIEvent Win32_ProcessStopTrace

Tags: powershell, wmi

I want the Windows system to react to start and stop of a certain .exe.

I managed to do that for notepad.exe with

```
Register-WMIEvent -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace WHERE ProcessName='notepad.exe'" -SourceIdentifier guiStarted -Action {
    ...
}
Register-WMIEvent -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace WHERE ProcessName='notepad.exe'" -SourceIdentifier guiStopped -Action {
    ...
}
```

But with the name of my own .exe (built using LabVIEW), I get only the start event, never the stop event. (I can verify in the Task Manager that the .exe is stopped.)

How does this event mechanism work? Is it dependent from how the application is programmed?

Comment: Are you sure they are registering properly?  You can't have two event subscribers called 'guiStarted ' (as in your code) - make one 'guiStopped' or similar.  Also, the event is based on the exact name of the executable that is launched.  For example, on Windows 10 using 'calc.exe' as the process name won't work, because although you can run the command 'calc.exe', it actually launches 'Calculator.exe'.

Comment: Yes sorry, copy/paste mistake in the post, the 2nd event is called guiStopped. When in these lines I replace notepad.exe with the name of my .exe, only the start works.

Comment: Is the process still running in Task Manager, even though its UI is gone?

Comment: No I am sure the process is dead.

Comment: Two other suggestions: What happens if you remove the WHERE clause from your WQL?  Also, try using the `__InstanceDeletionEvent` class instead, similar to the example shown in the help for [Register-WmiEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/register-wmievent?view=powershell-5.1).

Comment: Removing the WHERE was a good idea: it seems the name of the exe gets cut: $Event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.ProcessName returns "Development GUI.exe" by start and "Development GU" by stop.

Answer (score 1):

In the stop event the name of the process is cut to 14 characters, whereas in the start event the full name comes.

I do not understand why, maybe somebody has an idea?